# Can someone please edit this i keep getting a syntax error on line 13

Tags: python

```
class Tux(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tux, self).__init__()
        combobox = gtk.combo_box_new_text()
        combobox.connect("changed", self.on_changed)
        for choice in choices:
            combobox.append_text(choice)
        self.add(combobox)
        self.label = gtk.Label("No selection")
        self.add(self.label)
        img = gtk.Image( )
        img.set_from_file(“Tux image.png”)
        self.add(img)
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

def on_changed(self, widget):
    self.label.set_label(widget.get_active_text())


Tux()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Try replacing the quotes around Tux image.png with real quotes not Microsoft smart quotes.

Comment: Could you post the exact error you're getting ?

Comment: Which one is line #13? Is it `self.add(img)`?

Answer (score 3):

```
img.set_from_file(“Tux image.png”)
```

Python, like most programming languages, does not support fancy quotes (likely inserted by a word processor). Instead, use `"` or `'`.

Answer (score 0):

On line:

```
img.set_from_file(“Tux image.png”)
```

You should use (") or (') sign, not (”).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Tux(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tux, self).__init__()
        combobox = gtk.combo_box_new_text()
        combobox.connect("changed", self.on_changed)
        for choice in choices:
            combobox.append_text(choice)
        self.add(combobox)
        self.label = gtk.Label("No selection")
        self.add(self.label)
        img = gtk.Image( )
        img.set_from_file("Tux image.png")
        self.add(img)
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

    def on_changed(self, widget):
        self.label.set_label(widget.get_active_text())


Tux()
gtk.main()
```

Note for the future: use a real programming editor to write code, not MS Word. Word will munge your input.

Comment: it does not work i have a error it says that on_changed is not defined

Comment: @Liam: fixed the indentation. You'll still have to define `choices` yourself.